# Add username to Creditmemo Comments History

Tags: magento-1.7

I have created a module that adds the username of the logged in admin that adds a comment to an order. I now need to add this feature for Creditmemo but have hit a brick a wall.

Here's my code for order comment:

Controller

```
<?php

require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php';
class MyModule_OrderComment_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController
{
    /**
     * Add order comment action
     */
    public function addCommentAction()
    {
        if ($order = $this->_initOrder()) {
            try {
                $response = false;
                 //getting username
                $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
                $username = $user->getUser()->getUsername();
                $append = ".<br /> <br /> Posted by: ".$username."";
                $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('history');
                $notify = isset($data['is_customer_notified']) ? $data['is_customer_notified'] : false;
                $visible = isset($data['is_visible_on_front']) ? $data['is_visible_on_front'] : true;


                //appending username with markup to comment
                $order->addStatusHistoryComment($data['comment'].$append, $data['status'])
                    ->setIsVisibleOnFront($visible)
                    ->setIsCustomerNotified($notify);

                $comment = trim(strip_tags($data['comment']));

                $order->save();
                $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail($notify, $comment);

                $this->loadLayout('empty');
                $this->renderLayout();
            }
            catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $response = array(
                    'error'     => true,
                    'message'   => $e->getMessage(),
                );
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $response = array(
                    'error'     => true,
                    'message'   => $this->__('Cannot add order history.')
                );
            }
            if (is_array($response)) {
                $response = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response);
                $this->getResponse()->setBody($response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I have added this code to Adminhtml/Sales/Order/View/history.phtml

```
    <?php if ($_item->getComment()): ?>
        <br/><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getComment(), array('b','br','strong','i','u')) ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

And this to Adminhtml/Sales/Order/View/Tab/history.phtml

```
        <?php if ($_comment = $this->getItemComment($_item)): ?>
            <br/><?php echo $_comment ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Now my question is how do I amend the logic to do this for credit meme page?

Inside the same module Can I create a CreditmemoController.php? Could anyone tell me how/where I should alter the logic for Credit meme please?

Thanks guys...

Changed my config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyModule_OrderComment>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </MyModule_OrderComment>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <!--args>
                    <modules>
                        <MyModule_OrderComment_Adminhtml before="Mage_Adminhtml">MyModule_OrderComment_Adminhtml</MyModule_OrderComment_Adminhtml>
                    </modules>
                </args-->
            <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_addComment>
                <observers>
                    <ordercomment>
                        <class>MyModule_OrderComment_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>controllerActionPredispatchAdminhtmlSalesOrderAddComment</method>
                    </your_module_unique_node>
                </ordercomment>
            </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_addComment>
            <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_save>
                <observers>
                    <ordercomment>
                        <class>MyModule_OrderComment_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>controllerActionPredispatchAdminhtmlSalesOrderCreditmemoSave</method>
                    </ordercomment>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_save>
            <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_addComment>
                <observers>
                    <ordercomment>
                        <class>MyModule_OrderComment_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>controllerActionPredispatchAdminhtmlSalesOrderCreditmemoAddComment</method>
                    </ordercomment>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_addComment>
        </events>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>    
    <global>        
        <helpers>
            <exgrid>
                <class>MyModule_OrderComment_Helper</class>
            </exgrid>
        </helpers>
    </global>    
</config>
```

Added new Oberver.php to MyModule/OrderComment/Model/

```
<?php
//class MyModule_OrderComment_Model_Observer

function controllerActionPredispatchAdminhtmlSalesOrderAddComment($observer)
{
    $history = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('history');
    if ($history && isset($history['comment'])) {
        $history['comment'] .= $this->_getAppend();
        Mage::app()->getRequest()->setPost('history', $history);
    }
}
function controllerActionPredispatchAdminhtmlSalesOrderCreditmemoSave($observer)
{
    $post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('creditmemo');
    if ($post && isset($post['comment_text'])) {
        $post['comment_text'] .= $this->_getAppend();
        Mage::app()->getRequest()->setPost('creditmemo', $post);
    }
}
function controllerActionPredispatchAdminhtmlSalesOrderCreditmemoAddComment($observer)
{
    $post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('comment');
    if ($post && isset($post['comment'])) {
        $post['comment'] .= $this->_getAppend();
        Mage::app()->getRequest()->setPost('comment', $post);
    }
}
protected function _getAppend()
{
    $user     = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
    $username = $user->getUser()->getUsername();
    return "<br/><br/> Posted by: " . $username;
}
```

Removed my controller folder which contains OrderController.php

Have I done something incorrectly?

Comment: You config.xml is wrong. See this link: https://makandracards.com/magento/6219-config-event-observer-definition-frontend-admin-global

Comment: class MyModule_OrderComment_Model_Observer{//here is my functions}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I show you fast and standard way to do your task via observer. You shouldn't rewrite controller and templates.
/app/code/community/Your/Module/etc/config.xml

```
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_addComment>
                <observers>
                    <your_module_unique_node>
                        <class>Your_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>controllerActionPredispatchAdminhtmlSalesOrderAddComment</method>
                    </your_module_unique_node>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_addComment>
            <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_save>
                <observers>
                    <your_module_unique_node>
                        <class>Your_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>controllerActionPredispatchAdminhtmlSalesOrderCreditmemoSave</method>
                    </your_module_unique_node>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_save>
            <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_addComment>
                <observers>
                    <your_module_unique_node>
                        <class>SSD_Authorizenetcim_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>controllerActionPredispatchAdminhtmlSalesOrderCreditmemoAddComment</method>
                    </your_module_unique_node>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_addComment>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
```

And /app/code/community/Your/Module/Model/Observer.php

```
function controllerActionPredispatchAdminhtmlSalesOrderAddComment($observer)
{
    $history = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('history');
    if ($history && isset($history['comment'])) {
        $history['comment'] .= $this->_getAppend();
        Mage::app()->getRequest()->setPost('history', $history);
    }
}
function controllerActionPredispatchAdminhtmlSalesOrderCreditmemoSave($observer)
{
    $post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('creditmemo');
    if ($post && isset($post['comment_text'])) {
        $post['comment_text'] .= $this->_getAppend();
        Mage::app()->getRequest()->setPost('creditmemo', $post);
    }
}
function controllerActionPredispatchAdminhtmlSalesOrderCreditmemoAddComment($observer)
{
    $post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('comment');
    if ($post && isset($post['comment'])) {
        $post['comment'] .= $this->_getAppend();
        Mage::app()->getRequest()->setPost('comment', $post);
    }
}
protected function _getAppend()
{
    $user     = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
    $username = $user->getUser()->getUsername();
    return "<br/><br/> Posted by: " . $username;
}
```

Comment: pls see updated code...

Comment: Thanks, finally got it to work, brilliant solution for a simple problem!!